# How to install glibc-devel.i686

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, yum

So I am trying to install "glibc-devel.i686" in my Dockerfile for "arm64v8/oraclelinux:8" image.

But I'm getting an error saying -

```
No match for argument: glibc-devel.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-devel.i686
```

Here is what I am using inside my image-

```
RUN yum install -y glibc-devel.i686 krb5-devel
```

Is there any way to install this? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**Update:-
Here is my entire Dockerfile-**

```
FROM arm64v8/oraclelinux:8

# Setup basic environment stuff
ENV container docker
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ EST



# CCSMP dependent
RUN yum install -y glibc-devel.i686 krb5-devel
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN yum install -y make gcc java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tar perl maven svn

# Minor changes to image to get ccsmp to build
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm
RUN cp /usr/include/linux/stddef.h /usr/include/stddef.h


RUN wget https://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip
RUN unzip apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip && mv apache-ant-1.10.12/ /opt/ant

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr

ENV ANT_HOME="/usr/bin/ant"
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/ant:$PATH"




CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: Your arm64 environment isn't going to have access to i686 packages (because they won't run, since it's a completely different processor architecture). What exactly are you trying to do? You can of course just `yum install -y glibc-devel` to get the package appropriate for your architecture.